# If duplicate values change text in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column with different values but the same value could exist more than once. I have a formula that adds a number in front of the value if it the value in column B exist more than once.

The column can look like this:

1. 123
2. 234
3. 234
4. 123
5. 567

and when I use the formula it will end up like this.

1. 123(1)
2. 234(1)
3. 234(2)
4. 123(2)
5. 567

What I would like it to do is instead of adding (1) to the first value I want to add it to the second value. What I mean is the following:

I want it to look like this instead of how it looks above

1. 123
2. 234
3. 234(1)
4. 123(1)
5. 567

The formula I am using is the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5000,B1)>1,B1& " (" & COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1) & ")",B1)
```

is it Possible to change the formula in doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5000,B1)>1,IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)>1,B1& " (" & COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)-1 & ")",B1),B1)
```